# Are presheaf categories well-copowered?

Tags: category-theory

I am trying to proof the existence of a right adjoint to the functor $F_*\colon \mathrm{Set}^D \to \mathrm{Set}^C$ given by precomposing with a functor $F\colon C \to D$, where $C$ and $D$ are small categories, using the dual version of the special adjoint functor theorem.

One of the ingredients for this is that $\mathrm{Set}^C$ is well-copowered (in the sense that $(\mathrm{Set}^C)^{\mathrm{op}}$ is well powered), which means--assuming I got my dualization right--that the collection of isomorphism classes of epimorphisms $F \to G$ in $(F \downarrow \mathrm{Set}^C)$ is (isomorphic to) a set.

This seems like a well known fact, but I couldn't find any proof of it and also failed to think of one by myself. Any hints or references to why this should be true?

Comment: An overkill answer is to appeal to Theorem 1.58 in Adamek and Rosicky's _Locally Presentable and Accessible Categories_, which says that any [locally presentable category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/locally+presentable+category) is well-copowered. Zhen Lin's answer is obviously better here. The general result does tell you e.g. that the category of commutative rings is well-copowered, which is not obvious (though it can [also be proven directly](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04VM).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\mathcal{S}$ is a category with cokernel pairs and $\mathcal{C}$ is a non-empty small category, then $\mathcal{S}$ is well-copowered if and only if $[\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{S}]$ is. The key observation is this: a morphism in $[\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{S}]$ is an epimorphism if and only if all its components are, because being an epimorphism is something that can be detected by cokernel pairs, and cokernel pairs in $[\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{S}]$ are computed componentwise if $\mathcal{S}$ has them.

The point is that the epimorphisms in $\mathbf{Set}$ are surjections, so there is an obvious cardinality bound on the quotients of any given set.

Comment: I did already work out the connection between epimorphisms in $[\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{S}]$ and $\mathcal{S}$; however, I fail to see how the well-copoweredness of $\mathcal{S}$ transfers to that of $[\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{S}]$. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Two quotients in $[\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{S}]$ are isomorphic if and only if their components are isomorphic as quotients in $\mathcal{S}$.

Comment: Just to make sure that I get this right, since I am a bit insecure in such size matters: For each $F \in [\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{S}]$ and for each $C \in \mathcal{C}$ there is a set of isomorphism classes of quotients of $F( C )$ in $\mathcal{S}$. Since $\mathcal{C}$ is small, we can construct there product $\Pi_{C \in \mathcal{C}} \mathrm{Quot}(F( C ))$. Then $\mathrm{Quot}(F)$ should be in bijection with this set where $\mathrm{Quot}$ means collection of isomorphism classes of quotients. Is this correct? Is this too complicated?

Comment: That's not quite correct. Rather, there is an _injection_ from the set of isomorphism classes of quotients of $F$ to the set of tuples of isomorphism classes of quotients of etc.

Comment: Right, sorry. I think I get it now, thanks!